# Find a Container Control in Delphi XE3 FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I am looking for a container control in Delphi XE3 FireMonkey, which can:

1. Hold multiple controls inside of it so that I can move them together by moving the container control itself.
2. The container control itself should be transparent so that it will not show a border.

In the past, I used `TPanel` from the VCL. I set its `BevelInner` and `BevelOuter` to `bvNone` to hide the borders. However, in a FireMoney app, `TPanel` does not have such properties so I cannot hide its borders.

Comment: `FMX.Layouts.TLayout` - *A layout is a container for other graphical objects. Use the layouts when you need to organize multiple graphical controls under the same parent.*

Comment: (continued) And you can read more about various use cases [in here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/FireMonkey_Layouts_Strategies)

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Thank you very much. That's what I need.